# ruby version change error - "rvm install 3.1.3"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm, apple-m1

I am trying to update the ruby version from: 2.6.10p210 to 3.1.3.
When updating it with the "rvm" I get the following error.
I am working from my mac m1.
I appreciate any help !
I also tried to upgrade with "rvm" to other versions of ruby, like 3.1.0, 3.1.2, etc.
**code on console:

```
alvarobarrazaramos@MacBook-Pro-de-Alvaro src % rvm install 3.0.0 
ruby-3.0.0 - #removing src/ruby-3.0.0 - please wait
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/13.0/arm64/ruby-3.0.0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates bundle '/opt/homebrew/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem' is already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/alvarobarrazaramos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-3.0.0 - #downloading ruby-3.0.0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-3.0.0 - #extracting ruby-3.0.0 to /Users/alvarobarrazaramos/.rvm/src/ruby-3.0.0 - please wait
ruby-3.0.0 - #configuring - please wait
Error running 'env CFLAGS=-O3 -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include LDFLAGS=-L/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib ./configure --prefix=/Users/alvarobarrazaramos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0 --disable-install-doc --enable-shared',
please read /Users/alvarobarrazaramos/.rvm/log/1676851424_ruby-3.0.0/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
alvarobarrazaramos@MacBook-Pro-de-Alvaro src %
```

log message:

```
alvarobarrazaramos@MacBook-Pro-de-Alvaro src % cat /Users/alvarobarrazaramos/.rvm/log/1676851424_ruby-3.0.0/configure.log
checking for ruby... /usr/bin/ruby
tool/config.guess already exists
tool/config.sub already exists
checking build system type... aarch64-apple-darwin22.1.0
checking host system type... aarch64-apple-darwin22.1.0
checking target system type... aarch64-apple-darwin22.1.0
checking for ld... ld
checking for gcc-ar... no
checking for g++... g++
checking for gcc-nm... no
checking for gcc-ranlib... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/alvarobarrazaramos/.rvm/src/ruby-3.0.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
alvarobarrazaramos@MacBook-Pro-de-Alvaro src %
```

Comment: What error do you get? Please share the command you ran, the error message and the full stack trace.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your reply.
I updated the question with the code and the log.

Comment: And what does `config.log` say?